# The definition of integral forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

A $d$-closed differential form $\phi$ on $X$ is said to be integral if its cohomology class in the de Rham group, $[\phi]\in H^*(X,\mathbb{C})$, is in the image of the natural mapping:
$H^*(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^*(X,\mathbb{C})$.

But I also see an alternative definition: a form is called integral if its integral over any cycle is an integer.

I can't see how these two definitions agree. And I didn't see the second definition  when I was taking the manifold class. Moreover, I can't find any reference to show these two definitions agree. Can you show me the proof or tell me the reference?

Comment: $H^*(X;R)$ give functions which take as input homology classes and spits out elements of R. The map $H^*(X;R) \to H^*(X;S)$ where $R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism takes such a function to the same function, thought of as a map to $S$. That's all it is.

Comment: @MikeMiller I think this claim follows from the universal coefficient theorem right? Via $H^n(X,Z)\to H^n(X,R)$ is equal to the map $Hom(H_n(X),Z)\to Hom(H_n(X),R)$

Comment: @MikeMiller and I think the homology class you input is with coefficient Z right?

Comment: Actually yeah, you're right. Quite straightforward proof. I suggest writing that up as an answer. I will upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment above explains why things in the image of $H^*(X;\Bbb Z)$ take integer values on cycles. Here I explain the converse in more detail.

Let $C_i(X)$ be the $i$th graded piece of the singular chain complex with $\Bbb Z$ coefficients. Because $\Bbb Z$ is a PID, submodules of a free module are free, and so $\text{Im}_{i-1}(d) \subset C_{i-1}(X)$ is free. Using this freeness, you may find a subset $N \subset C_i(X)$ so that $d: N \to \text{Im}_{i-1}(d)$ is an isomorphism. Then clearly we have $C_i(X) = K \oplus N$, where $K$ is the subcomplex of cycles (aka, $K = \text{ker}_i(d)$).

Now I assume you have a complex-valued cocycle $\varphi: C_i(X) \to \Bbb C$ so that, on any cycle $c$, the complex number $\varphi(c)$ is an integer. Define $\varphi': C_i(X) \to \Bbb Z$ so that $\varphi'(N) = 0$ and $\varphi' = \varphi$ on $K$. Then $\varphi$ is valued in $\Bbb Z$. Furthermore, $(\delta \varphi')(c) = \varphi'(dc) = 0$ for any chain in $C_{i+1}(X)$, because $dc \in K$ and we have the corresponding property for $\varphi$.

Therefore $\varphi'$ is an integer-valued cocycle. To see that it is cohomologous to $\varphi$, I suggest using the universal coefficient theorem for fields, $H^n(X;k) \cong \text{Hom}(H_n(X;\Bbb Z), k)$. In particular, $k$-valued cocycles which take the same values on homology classes are cohomologous. Of course, since $\varphi = \varphi'$ on cycles, this is true.

Comment: Why does  $H^n(X;R)$ give functions which take as input homology classes and spits out elements of $R$? Shouldn't the input be homology classes with degree $n$ by universal coefficient theorem?

Comment: @Danny I meant homology classes of degree $n$. Sorry for not being explicit.

Comment: So "a form is called integral if its integral over any cycle is an integer." should not be any cycle, but the the cycles with the same degree as the form right?

Comment: Yes. I think this is clear from context.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explaination